# Pass file between pages - UWP C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I'm wondering what is the best way to pass a file between pages in a UWP app?

I have a UWP app with two pages. In the first page, I have the user open a file with filepicker and load that file into a media player.

I want to pass that same file onto the second page when the user navigates there. I am passing the file over currently as a string which I then am attempting load as a storagefile using GetFileFromPathAsync.

This currently works as I'm able to load the file on the second page but it requires that the user provide broad file system access.

**Code on Page 1 (FileLoaded is file path string):**

```
private async void TranscodeMedia_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AppWindow appWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
            Frame appWindowContentFrame = new Frame();
            appWindowContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(TranscodeMedia), FileLoaded);
```

**Code on Page 2:**

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var fileTransfer = e.Parameter.ToString();

        FileName.Text = fileTransfer;

        StorageFile PassedFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileTransfer);
```

I'm wondering if this is the best way to pass the file between pages? I'd rather not require the user to provide broad system access to the app if possible. Any help you can provide is most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and most standard way in C#/WPF/UWP way is to use a standard pattern that consist of a general ViewModel class (which contains all the common app data that you want to use in the logic layer), put as a field in the **static** MainPage (or even in the App.xaml.cs class).

I always do it like this:

**1)** I use the MainPage automatically created as the "shell" of the app, with a property that is the `AppViewModel`.
The MainPage (and thus the `AppViewModel`) can be accessed from everywhere in the app, by setting itself as a **static** field in its own class (the "Current" static field can be called from everywhere in the app... even in a MessageDialog class!).

This is the code for the MainPage (or a shell Page that you wish, but I suggest doing like this, it is a pretty standard way used even by Microsoft), simpler than you think:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public AppViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new AppViewModel();
    public static MainPage Current { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
    }
}
```

> THIS is the trick: to make the page ***static*** in one field in its
>   own class, so that that static field will be UNIQUE in the entire app
>   (this is one of the main features of the "static" word) and, thus, by calling
>   `MainPage.Current.ViewModel` you can immediately get any data (in your
>   specific case, a StorageFile) stored there.

**2)** The `AppViewModel` itself is a class that must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, in order to enable bindable properties and functions.
It is common, among Windows developers, to create a base class that implements it and then derive all the classes that needs bindable (i.e. observable) properties from it.

Here it is, exactly how Microsoft itself creates it:

```
public class BaseBind : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you derive `AppViewModel` class (and all the other model and viewmodel classes) from it… populating it with all the common properties that you need to share across pages.
I have even added a derived property, in order to show how you can share even multiple data types at once, and a function:

```
public class AppViewModel : BaseBind
{
    public AppViewModel()
    {
        // Usually we initialize all the starting data here, in the viewmodel constructor...
    }

    // All common app data
    private string sampleCommonString;
    public String SampleCommonString
    {
        get { return sampleCommonString; }
        set { SetProperty(ref sampleCommonString, value); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SampleDerivedProperty1)); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SampleDerivedProperty2)); }
    }

    public String SampleDerivedProperty1 =>  "return something based on SampleCommonString";

    public String SampleDerivedProperty2
    {
        get
        {
            // evaluate in some way SampleCommonString...

            return "Same thing as SampleDerivedProperty1, but it allows to add more than just one istruction";
        }
    }

    // This is a property that you can use for functions and internal logic… but it CAN'T be binded to the UI directly
    public String SampleNOTBindableProperty { get; set; }

    public void SampleFunction()
    {
        // Insert code, that needs to interact with all the data contained in the viewmodel itself, here...

        // The function has to be with NO parameters, in order to work with simple {x:Bind} markup.
        // If your function has to access some specific data, you can create a new bindable (or non) property, just as the ones above, and memorize the data there.
    }
}
```

3) Then, in order to access all this from another `Page`, just create an `AppViewModel` field in that page, referencing the viewmodel contained in the static mainpage:

```
public sealed partial class SecondPage : Page
{
    public AppViewModel ViewModel => MainPage.Current.ViewModel;

    public SecondPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

...and you can easily bind XAML controls properties to the `AppViewModel` itself:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleCommonString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
<TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleCommonString, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Content="Sample content" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleFunction}"/>
```

(`Mode=OneWay` is for real-time binding, in order that the property is immediately updated even in the UI, while `Mode=TwoWay` is used for those properties that can be edited from the control itself, by the user, in order to interact with app logic).

In this mode you will be able to display data and all its changes in real-time!

> So... this is the way to keep all the app data at run-time in a
>   correct and flexible way... by learning it and practicing, in the
>   future you will use this pattern even in a smarter way, by creating
>   viewmodels for every *object* of your application (for example: if
>   your app need to store your company's customers data, you will have a
>   "CustomerViewModel" class derived from the BaseBind class, with all
>   the data of a customer in it) and creating lists like
>   `ObservableCollection<SampleViewModel>` to store all of them (`ObservableCollection<t>` is a collection type that has built-in mechanism to handle list changes, like adding, removing and reordering list items).
>   Then you will link every observable collection to the `ItemsSource` property of a control that inherits from ListBase class (tipically: `ListView` or `GridView`), creating a DataTemplate to display each list item, like in this example:

```
<Page
    xmlns:vm="using:SampleApp.ViewModelsPath"

    <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.SampleListOfObjectViewModel, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:SampleObjectViewModel">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SampleObjectProperty1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SampleObjectProperty2, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Button Click="{x:Bind SampleObjectFunction}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

...and all the data displayed will be updated in real-time whenever you change it!

Hope this all will help you boost your knowledge about how preparing a WPF/UWP *logic layer*, because all of this works pretty in the same way even for the WPF apps (i.e. the old desktop programs).

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There are some other ways to implement your requirement about accessing the same file on different pages. But for your scenario, you could use **Future-access list** in your UWP app.

By picking files and folders, your user grants your app permission to access items that might not be accessible otherwise. If you add these items to your **future-access list** then you'll retain that permission when your app wants to access those items again later.

Here is the sample code I made

**In the first page:**

```
        FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();

        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null) 
        {
            // add file to the Future Access list
            var storageItemAccessList = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList;
            // this token is the key to get the file.
            string FALToken = storageItemAccessList.Add(file, "mediaFile");
            // in your real scenario, you need to save the token and pass it when you nee
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(TestPage), FALToken);
        }
```

**In the second page:**

```
   protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string token = (string)e.Parameter;

        var storageItemAccessList = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList;

        StorageFile retrievedFile = await storageItemAccessList.GetFileAsync(token);


    }
```

So you don't need the broad file system access if you use **Future-access list** to keep the permission of files.

For more detailed information, please refer to this document: [Track recently used files and folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders)

Comment: Nope, that is not the correct way to keep file (or ANY data) in the app running. The correct way is by using the MVVM pattern, through an app viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks @RoyLi-MSFT for the suggestion. That sounds like exactly the solution I was looking for. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: @Luca Thanks for the insight. I'm fairly new to development and MVVM pattern sounds like a great way to build. Do you have any resources to get antiquated with this and by chance be able to roughly explain how you would pass files between pages when using MVVM pattern? Sounds like you would get the file in a Model and pass it on to either of the ViewModels?

Comment: @HooptyDoopty It is even simpler than that! Now I’ll post a complete answer here with a minimal working code, so that you can test it for yourself.