# How to share a view model in C++ UWP?

Tags: c++, mvvm, uwp, c++-winrt

How can I share a view model between different pages in a C++ UWP application?

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62053435/7571171) is a C# solution which uses a static property:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public AppViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new AppViewModel();
    public static MainPage Current { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
    }
}
```

But I am having trouble translating that into C++.

My C++ `MainPage` currently looks like this:

```cpp
namespace winrt::myproject::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();

        myproject::MainViewModel MainViewModel() const { return this->mainViewModel; }

    private:
        myproject::MainViewModel mainViewModel{ nullptr };
    };
}
```

The view model instance is created in the `MainPage()` constructor using

```cpp
this->mainViewModel = winrt::make<myproject::implementation::MainViewModel>();
```

And the `.idl` file simply lists the view model instance as a property:

```
[default_interface]
runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
{
    MainPage();

    MainViewModel MainViewModel{ get; };
}
```

---

How can I share the `MainViewModel` between all of my pages?

- What do I need to change in the `.idl` and in the `.h` file?
- Do I need to use `std::shared_ptr<myproject::MainViewModel>` or `winrt::comptr<myproject::MainViewModel>` to avoid copying the struct and to really *share* the same instance?

Comment: You don't have to change anything. You're already passing around the projected type `MainViewModel` of your view model. Projected types are represented as `comptr` class template instantiations. Like anything COM they are reference counted shared pointers to the same implementation class instance.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you very much for clearing that up! It works now. If your comment was an answer, I'd happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myproject::MainViewModel` ultimately derives from [`winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/windows-foundation-iunknown). It is this structure that implements all the reference counting machinery, turning each derived type into a shared pointer to its interface.

The following implementation

```cpp
myproject::MainViewModel MainViewModel() const { return this->mainViewModel; }
```

invokes the [`IUnknown::IUnknown(IUnknown const& other)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/windows-foundation-iunknown#iunknowniunknown-constructor) copy-c'tor that increments the reference count on `other` and constructs an `IUnknown` instance holding the same pointer. Both `this->mainViewModel` and the return value point to the same object.

In general, copying structures that represent projected types performs a shallow copy. Only the pointer to the object is copied, and the reference count is incremented. Like a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) the operation is thread-safe and has comparable overhead.

A lot more information on the internals and use of *projected types* can be found at [Consume APIs with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis).